# Momentum in capacitor field; How can an EM field have zero momentum density but non-zero momentum flux?

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, tensor-calculus, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, stress-strain

Consider the case of a simple, stationary parallel plate capacitor oriented with its plates lying in the x-y plane. The E-field is simply given by:

$$\vec{E} = \frac{Q}{\epsilon_0A}\hat{z} $$

with the B-field of course being 0.

Evaluating the stress-energy tensor for this system gives me:

$$\mathbb{T} =  \frac{Q^2}{2\epsilon_0A^2} \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

As far as I understand the interpretation of the Maxwell-stress tensor, the (0,0) entry is simply the electromagnetic energy density. The (1,1)/(2,2)/(3,3) entries are the momentum flow (or equivalently force) of x-momentum in the x-direction/y-momentum in the y-direction/z-momentum in the z-direction.
I also understand that the fact that the (3,3) entry is negative means that there is tension in the z-direction and the plates attract each other.

My problem lies in the interpretation of the (1,1) and (2,2) entries. I've got two main problems:

1) What exactly do these entries physically represent? Why is there an outwards pressure in the x- and y-directions?

2) The momentum density of the EM-field is given by $\mathbf {\vec{g}} = \frac{\vec{S}}{c^2} = \epsilon_0\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$. In this case the momentum density of the EM-field is zero as $\vec{B} = 0$. How is it possible that there is a non-zero momentum flow between the capacitor plates but the momentum density itself is zero?

Comment: If I push against a wall, my hand is transfering momentum to the wall. Thus there is a momentum *flux* even though there is no momentum *density*. The same is true with the elastic  stress tensor in a solid.

Comment: Due to the Earth's magnetic field, there actually _is_ momentum density. The Poynting vector is counter intuitive for stationary fields.